# How to prove limsup||=max{|limsup|,|liminf|}?

Tags: real-analysis

Basically the title,

I do not know how to approach this.

I have that

$$\inf a_n \le \sup a_n \le \sup |a_n|$$

but I'm not sure how to proceed to the conclusion that:

$$\limsup |a_n| = \max\{ \limsup a_n, \liminf a_n \}$$

Comment: Hint: $\lim \sup (a_n)=-\lim \inf (-a_n)$